# How to get TypesScript nested type inference to stop giving spurious type error

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a type (created via using typeof on an object) which describes my database:

```
type DATABASE_METADATA = typeof databaseMetadata;
let databaseMetadata = {
    "management": {
        "databaseName": "management",
        "public": {
            "schemaName": "public",
            "tables": {
                "secrets": {
                    "example_type": null as any as { x: number },
                },
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I wrote types for a function which will eventually be insert a value into the database, using my database types to ensure my database, schema, table, and value are all type checked:

```
function createAndInsertSql2<DatabaseName extends keyof DATABASE_METADATA>(
    databaseName: DatabaseName
) {
    type Database = DATABASE_METADATA[DatabaseName];
    return function<SchemaName extends keyof Database>(
        schemaName: SchemaName
    ) {
        type Schema = Database[SchemaName];
        return function <TableName extends keyof Schema["tables"])> (
            tableName: TableName,
            value: Schema["tables"][TableName]["example_type"],
        ) {
            // Insert value into database with name databaseName, schema schemaName and table tableName.
        };
    };
}
```

However, this generates type errors, starting with `Schema["tables"]`, with the error being: `Type '"tables"' cannot be used to index type 'Schema'.(2536)` .

This is especially annoying as the use of the function actually type checks correctly, so Typescript is inferencing what type I want... it just thinks it can't?

```
// Does not give a type error
createAndInsertSql2("management")("public")("secrets", { x: 5 });

// Gives a type error
createAndInsertSql2("management")("public")("secrets", { });
```

How can I change my function definition to remove the type errors, while still inferring and type checking the type for `example_type`?

Comment: What is supposed to happen if you call `createAndInsertSql2("management")("databaseName")`?  The compiler is rightfully worried that there is no `tables` property there.

Comment: You *could* change the definition of `Schema` to `type Schema = Extract<Database[SchemaName], { tables: any }>;` which will essentially tell the compiler that it can blithely index into the `tables` property there and any subproperty you care to use.  But I really don't understand the use case to know if this suffices; it's not like this example actually does anything inside the function so I'm not sure what the implications of suppressing the errors in the implementation are.

Comment: Ah, you're right, there isn't a constraint to make sure only keys with "tables" properties are passed.

Answer (score 0):

@jcalz's comment put me on the right track (I wasn't constraining the SchemaName enough, so it could be values which would actually have broken the function). Figuring that out helped me write something that works. I'm going to leave the question open in case anyone else has a different approach.

```
type DATABASE_METADATA = typeof databaseMetadata;
let databaseMetadata = {
    "management": {
        "databaseName": "management",    
        "public": {
            "schemaName": "public",
            "tables": {
                "secrets": {
                    "example_type": null as any as { x: number },
                },
            }
        }
    }
};

export async function createAndInsertSql<
    DatabaseName extends keyof DATABASE_METADATA,
    Database extends DATABASE_METADATA[DatabaseName],
    SchemaName extends keyof Database,
    SchemaType extends Database[SchemaName] & { tables: unknown },
    TableName extends keyof SchemaType["tables"],
    TableType extends SchemaType["tables"][TableName] & { example_type: unknown },
    ValueType extends TableType["example_type"]
>(
    databaseName: DatabaseName,
    schemaName: SchemaName & string,
    tableName: TableName & string,
    value: ValueType,
) {
    // Insert value into databaseName, under schemaName, in tableName
}

// Does not give a type error
createAndInsertSql("management", "public", "secrets", { x: 5 });

// Gives a type error
createAndInsertSql("management", "public", "secrets", { });
```